# how to watch multiple values or data change generically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this in a component. As you can see I'm watching for changes and then run an update function to update the database via an api call.
Is there a way to strip the duplicate code and just watch for data changes in general? Or combine watching for several values.

```
watch: {
    mutable_threshold_value: function(val, oldVal) {
        this.update();
    },
    mutable_minimal_margin_fixed_value: function(val, oldVal) {
        this.update();
    },
    mutable_value_percentage: function(val, oldVal) {
        this.update();
    },
},
methods: {
    update: function() {
        this.$http.patch('/api/v1.0/margin-steps/' + this.id, {
            params: {
                threshold_value: this.mutable_threshold_value,
                minimal_margin_fixed_value: this.mutable_minimal_margin_fixed_value,
                value_percentage: this.mutable_value_percentage
            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assemble `treshold_value`, `minimal_margin_fixed_value` and `value_percentage` into a computed property `payload`. This payload is what you send to the api. Because of how computed properties work, the computed property watches the variables it depends on. If they change, the payload changes, and thus the watcher is called. Watch this new `payload` variable instead and send the payload to the server whenever it changes.

```
computed: {
    payload () {
        return {
            threshold_value: this.mutable_threshold_value,
            minimal_margin_fixed_value: this.mutable_minimal_margin_fixed_value,
            value_percentage: this.mutable_value_percentage
        }
    }
},
watch: {
    payload () {
        this.update();
    }
},
methods: {
    update: function() {
        this.$http.patch('/api/v1.0/margin-steps/' + this.id, {
            params: this.payload
        });
    },
}
```